# Regression using abnormal returns or cumulative abnormal returns

Tags: regression, finance

I am studying the impact of option expiration on the underlying stocks' returns and I performed an event study using eventstudytools. To summarise, options expire on the third Friday of each month (except when Fridays are holidays). Therefore, I defined each Friday as event dates and used the market model to estimate the expected returns. Thanks to the event study calculator, I got detail of all AR, AAR, CAR and CAAR. Moreover, the calculator allows to sub-group my data for AAR and CAAR calculations as I want to compare two periods (2008-2009 with 2010-2018).

As a further step, I would like to use the ARs(0) (at event dates) **or** CARs in a single regression over the two periods with a dummy equal to 1 if in the second period and 0 if in the first period in order to estimate the difference between the two periods. However, I don't manage to set an equation as I only have one dummy.

Would you have any suggestion for a model? 
If any editing of the question is needed, do not hesitate to let me know. Thanks for your help

Comment: On Cross Validated, AR is much more commonly used for autoregression than abnormal returns, so I updated your title to prevent confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the update